# ¿Cómo abrir una modal de Bootstrap desde AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un botón con un id:

```
 <li id="motivo" class="nav-item nav-elemento rounded " ><a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Agregar Motivo"  style="position:relative;"> <i class="fas fa-clipboard" style="color:black;font-size:14px;"></i><i class="fas fa-exclamation" style="position: absolute; right:0.25rem;bottom:0.25rem;font-size:0.75rem;color:black;"></i></a></li>
```

y tengo este codigo de ajax, el cual deseo que cuando doy click al botón de arriba, aparezca una modal de bootstrap con un formulario usando el ajax de aquí abajo

```
 $('#motivo_rechazo').click(function (ID_SOLICITUD){
  var nombre;
    var solicitudes_id;
    $.map( $('#table_solicitudes_nombre').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
        nombre = row.NOMBRE;
        solicitudes_id = row.solicitudes_id;
    });
   if(!nombre){
        swal({title: "Advertencia",text: "Debe seleccionar una solicitud para generar el motivo.",icon: "warning"}); 
    } else {
    


     });
```

en ese `else`, debería tener la modal de bootstrap con un campo de texto con su id y su botón de aceptar para que, cuando el campo se llene, se guarde en la bd

```
  .then((confirm) => {
            if (confirm) {
                $.ajax({
                    timeout: 30000, //30 segundos
                    url:"controlador/rechazarUsuario",
                    type:"post",
                    datatype:"json",
                    data:{'solicitud_id': solicitud_id,
                        'nombre':nombre},
                    error: function(){
                        $('#no_respuesta').modal('show');
                    },
                    success:function(rechazarUsuario){
                        if(rechazarUsuario){
                            if(rechazarUsuario == 1){
                                swal({title: "Éxito",text: "Solicitud de usuario rechazada.",icon: "success"});
                                $("#modal_solicitar_usuario").modal("hide");
                                update_solicitudes_pendientes();
                            }else{
                                swal({title: "Error",text: "Hubo un problema al rechazar la solicitud.",icon: "error"});
                                $("#modal_solicitar_usuario").modal("hide");
                                update_solicitudes_pendientes();
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
```

Comment: Que version de bootstrap estas usando?

Comment: la version 4 de bootstrap

Comment: intentaste? te ha funcionado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boton HTML

```
<li class="nav-item nav-elemento rounded " ><a class="nav-link" href="#motivo" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Agregar Motivo"  style="position:relative;"> <i class="fas fa-clipboard" style="color:black;font-size:14px;"></i><i class="fas fa-exclamation" style="position: absolute; right:0.25rem;bottom:0.25rem;font-size:0.75rem;color:black;"></i></a></li>
```

Al hacer click se abra el modal

```
$('a[href$="#motivo"]').on( "click", function() {
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

añades el codigo HTML que corresponde al modal

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Y dentro del modal colocas la información que necesites.
el resto de tu codigo javascript puedes ponerlo dentro de la funcion click que abre el modal.